# Why I can not drop sudo root privileges?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, system-calls, setuid

I am debugging a program and not quite sure why I can not drop privileges.

I have root permissions via `sudo` and I can call `setgid/setuid`, but the operation `[is]` is not supported.

Basic code to reproduce (golang):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    if os.Getuid() != 0 {
        fmt.Println("run as root")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    uid, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("SUDO_UID"))
    check("", err)

    gid, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("SUDO_GID"))
    check("", err)

    fmt.Printf("uid: %d, gid: %d\n", uid, gid)

    check("gid", syscall.Setgid(gid))
    check("uid", syscall.Setuid(uid))
}

func check(message string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", message, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
$ sudo ./drop-sudo 
uid: 1000, gid: 1000
gid: operation not supported
```

System info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux user2460234 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I don't know if this ever got fixed, but Setuid/Setgid do not work properly with Go on Linux - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435

Comment: comment out the Setuid line and see if Setgid works.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro that doesn't work either; they are in the right order (setgid before setuid).

Comment: Yeah, they are, it was just a test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your programming language simply does not support such things.

It's complex to do this stuff on Linux, because of the architecture of Linux.  The C libraries (e.g. GNU and musl) hide this complexity.  It continues to be one of the known problems with threads on Linux.

The Go language does not replicate the mechanism of the C libraries.  [The current implementation of those functions](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d970519086765367f545186d860080059c69fad8/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go#L957) is not a system call, and has not been [since 2014](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/343b4ba8c1ad8a29b6dd19cb101273b57a26c9b0).

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2010). *[The known problems with threads on Linux](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/linux-thread-problems.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- Michał Derkacz (2011-01-21). *[syscall: Setuid/Setgid doesn't apply to all threads on Linux](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435)*. Go bug #1435

Comment: "The known problems with threads on Linux" still stands with current kernel(s)?

Comment: It should be supported as of go v1.16.6. I tested this today
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1435

Answer (score 1):

You can check with [libcap](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/getting-started-with-go/using-go-to-set-uid-and-gids), it has an [official go library](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/go) with [examples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/goapps/setid/setid.go). The example uses `psx.Syscall3(syscall.SYS_SETUID,...)` to set uid (as [@JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/469473/46274) said, go removes implementation for `syscall.Setuid()`). The [psx](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/psx/README) library is part of libcap.

> Package psx provides a CGo backed API for invoking system calls in a
> way that each system call is mirrored on all pthreads of the combined
> Go/CGo runtime. Since the Go runtime treats all pthreads as
> interchangeable, a feature like this is needed to meaningfully change
> process privilege (including dropping privilege) in a Go program
> running on Linux

Answer (score 1):

As of [go 1.16](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#minor_library_changes), `syscall.Setuid()` and friends are fully supported under Linux.

That is, the reproducer program provided in this question, compiled using the go1.16 toolchain under Linux, will build a program that works as intended. All of the observations that it doesn't work are only true of earlier go toolchain releases under Linux.

The [psx](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/psx) package can be used to make something like it work in earlier go toolchains too (as noted by ivzhh).

Comment: you need to give more relevant explanation and how your answer would help

Comment: @FargolK I have reworded it and added some links to further information.